# How I tell a person to give me a missed call

Tags: grammar, word-choice, sentence-construction, american-english, sentence-usage

Is the sentence correct? `Give me a reminder call when you are ready` ?.

**Context**: I scheduled a meeting with someone at 1 pm. But the person is not responding on chat at 1 pm. So I don't want to keep checking messages or the persons' reply. Instead, I want to tell him to give me a missed call so that I will come to know he is available.   I am not sure how else to express this or is there a better way to say this.

Is saying `give me a missed call` correct? It feels like the person may ring my mobile for a sec and then disconnect and so I may not be able to hear the ring in case of a short missed call

Comment: *Give me a missed call* doesn't make any sense.  A *missed call* is a call that you did not answer.  Whether you answer it or not is up to you, not the caller!

Comment: If you mean specifically where you let the phone ring once and hang up to alert someone without having to pay the cost of a phone call (or to avoid their wife answering, or whatever reason), there's a question [on English Language and Usage SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/198500/verb-for-calling-a-phone-only-with-the-intention-of-letting-it-ring) but there isn't a very good, widely understood English term. Not sure that people do this any more, since phone calls are cheap and instant messaging is ubiquitous, but maybe it's still done somewhere.

Comment: @stangdon "*Give someone a missed call*" is a common phrase, at least in North America meaning to call someone, but hang up before they answer. This is useful for giving someone your phone number without having to type it into their phone. In this context, the OP is using it to get a clear notification that someone is ready.

Comment: @gotube  I'm in North America, and I've never heard "give someone a missed call".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Give me a missed call" is correct and natural.

Based on the comments, not everyone is familiar with the expression though, so it might not be understood.

To be safe, I'd say something like:

> When you're ready for the meeting, please call my phone and just make it ring. I'll reject the call and join our meeting.

Answer (score 1):

"Give me a missed call" is meaningless (to me).  It has no use in British English and is oxymoronic.  If you call someone one, there is no way to arrange that they will be unable to receive your call.

Based on comments, there was at one time a habit to call, allow for a single ring and then hang up (to avoid paying the cost of a call).  Nowadays calls are so cheap that they often unmetered, and other messaging services exist, making this redundant.

You would just say "give me a call". You can choose to answer or not.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard people say "*Leave a missed call letting me know when …*", meaning to leave a voice-mail message because I likely won't be able to answer.
But I think such usage is very regional.

More common is [make a call and disconnect after ringing to leave a missed call - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11545379/android-make-a-call-and-disconnect-after-ringing-to-leave-a-missed-call), where the intent is simply to leave one's number without any message.

For instance, a "for sale" ad might say "*Leave a missed call at 555-2368 and I'll get back to you.*".
Again though, this might be very regional usage, and not universally understood.